# put text in xml file

Tags: php, xml

i have simple xml file(`product.xml`):-

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1"/>
      <dist_activity value="10066"/>
      <dist_region value="4332"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
      <tab_name value="test2"/>
      <dist_activity value="10067"/>
      <dist_region value="4333"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

i have two text file:-
one have contains `dist_activity id` name is `activity.txt` 
second have contains `dist_region id` name is `region.txt`
this is activity.txt;-

```
10066,10067,10068,10069,10070,10071,10072,5
```

this is region.txt:-

```
4332,4333,4334,4335,4336,4337,4338,4339
```

i want to create more product_id in my `product.xml` file and set there value `dist_activity` and `dist_region` from one by one in `txt` file.
i am try this :-

```
    <?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('product.xml');
$employee = $xml->addChild('product_id value="3"');
$employee->addChild('tab_id value="253"');
$employee->addChild('tab_name value="test3"');
$employee->addchild('dist_activity value="10068"');
$employee->addchild('dist_region value="10069"');
file_put_contents('prod.xml', $xml->asXML());
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Nobody will give you a working solution for this.

Comment: @BenjaminPaap i am add my try please check...

Comment: please consider to acceppt an answer if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Jack, I see two issues with your question:

(1) **wrong use** of `addChild`

```
<example>
    <lisa kevin="thomas">cathy</lisa>
</example>

lisa = node name, child-node of <example>
cathy = node value
kevin = attribute name (of node lisa)
thomas = attribute value

syntax:
addChild(name, value)
addAttribute(name, value)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php

(2) no solution for how to **pull values from your comma-seperated file** `activity.txt`and your other txt-file...

I'd suggest `file_get_contents`and `explode`

Feel free to come back with specific questions after you've tried something, have fun!